# So I need to input a table onto SAS but I can't figure out how to make characters appear

Tags: sas

So the data should be mostly character

```
 data pounds;
 input name $1-14 from 16-30 to 32-41 pounds_million $ 44-47
 datalines;
 Angel Di Maria Real Madrid     Man United  59.7
 Diego Costa    Atletico Madrid Chelsea     32
 Cesc Fabregas  Barcelona       Chelsea     27
 Romelu Lukaku  Chelsea         Everton     28
 ;

  run;
  proc print = pounds;
  var name from to pounds_million;
  run;
```

I realize that this is probably very trivial but this is my first time using SAS

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@` (the pointer) and `$x.` (the length of the character variable, x), and the `:` modifier to force it to read the spaces as part of the variable e.g.

```
data pounds ;
  input @1  name : $14.
        @16 from : $15.
        @32 to   : $10.
        @44 pounds_million 
        ;
/*
RULER
         1         2         3         4         5
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
*/
datalines ;
Angel Di Maria Real Madrid     Man United  59.7
Diego Costa    Atletico Madrid Chelsea     32
Cesc Fabregas  Barcelona       Chelsea     27
Romelu Lukaku  Chelsea         Everton     28
;
run ;
```

SAS infile statement documentation > https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm

SAS input statement documentation > https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146292.htm

Comment: What is `:` doing in this context exactly?  I'm fairly sure it's incorrect - leave it out and it will read correctly.

Comment: when removing the `:` ,the $20 for third variable is wrong , it will also read the pounds in the variable. It has to be $10.

Comment: Edited to 10, it was late, my maths was wrong, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  The `$` shows that a variable is character; you have it correctly on the first variable, but incorrectly on the fourth, and incorrectly *not* on the second and third.  You're also off by one on your positions.

```
 data pounds;
 input name $1-15 from $ 17-31 to $ 33-43 pounds_million 44-47;
 datalines;
 Angel Di Maria Real Madrid     Man United  59.7
 Diego Costa    Atletico Madrid Chelsea     32
 Cesc Fabregas  Barcelona       Chelsea     27
 Romelu Lukaku  Chelsea         Everton     28
 ;

  run;
  proc print data = pounds;
  var name from to pounds_million;
  run;
```